# Why var is not updated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have the following code in jQuery

```
var fila;
$(document).ready(function(){
   acciones_filas('tbl_producto', 'acciones-activos', productoTable);
   $("#id_producto").val(fila.nProCodigo);
}

function acciones_filas(tabla_id, acciones_id, tabla_objeto, fila)
{
    //click on a row
    $("#"+tabla_id+" tbody").on('click', 'tr', function(){
        $("#"+acciones_id+" .btn").removeAttr('disabled');
        if ( $(this).hasClass('row_selected') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('row_selected');
        }
        else {
            tabla_objeto.$('tr.row_selected').removeClass('row_selected');
            $(this).addClass('row_selected');
        }

        if($('#'+tabla_id+' .row_selected').length < 1)
            $("#"+acciones_id+" button").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        fila = tabla_objeto.fnGetData(this); 
    });
}
```

When I click on a row of a table the variable `fila` must save the value of the selected row, but when I print the result I get and `undefined`

Comment: Don't include `fila` in the argument list of `acciones_filas`, it will become a local variable, and shadow the global `fila` within the function.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to delete that.

Comment: @Teemu that solved it, thanks

Comment: But is it working now that you removed it?

Comment: @LeWoogush yes... is it weird?

Comment: @laviku Nope, it just means the problem is fixed and an answer should be accepted, I would also suggest to undo the edit to the main post so other users with a similar problem can find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On you context, you have two vars `fila`. One inside the function, other outside. Javascript will try to use the one that is closer. On that case, the argument of the function `acciones_filas`.

Give a look on point 8 of that link: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)